# Single Shared Database, Fluent NHibernate, Many clients

Tags: c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I am working on inventory application (C# .net 4.0) that will simultaneously inventory dozens of workstations and write the results to a central database.    To save me having to write a DAL I am thinking of using Fluent NHibernate which I have never used before.

It is safe and good practice to allow the inventory application which runs as a standalone application to talk directly to the database using Nhibernate?  Or should I be using a client server model where all access to the database is via a server which then reads/writes to database.   In other words if 50 workstations when currently being inventoried there would be 50 active DB sessions.  I am thinking of using GUID-Comb for the PK ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the environment in which your application will be deployed, you should also consider that direct database connections to a central server might not always be allowed for security reasons.

Creating a simple REST Service with WCF (using `WebServiceHost`) and simply POST'ing or PUT'ing your inventory data (using `HttpClient`) might provide a good alternative.

As a result, clients can get very simple and can be written for other systems easily (linux? android?) and the server has full control over how and where data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

it depends ;)

NHibernate has optimistic concurrency control ootb which is good enough for many situations. So if you just create data on 50 different stations there should be no problem. If creating data on one station depends on data from all stations it gets tricky and a central server would help.